# strophe muc decline group invite stanza

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmpp, strophe

Hi I am having problems on decline invite to chat room. This is my stanza:

```
var msg = $msg({"from" : tojid,"to" : room}).c("x", {"xmlns" : Strophe.NS.MUC_USER}).c("decline", {"to" : fromjid+"@188.2.16.19"});

msg.c("reason").t("Can talk right now.");
Chat.connection.send(msg.tree());
```

But that is not sent first time and invitation is not declined. It keeps returning all time.
If I send that twice on sender end I have response:

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><message xmlns="jabber:client" from="epthi_702@conference.188.2.16.19" to="nikola_degree361_com@188.2.16.19"><x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user"><decline from="nikola_pregmatch_org@188.2.16.19"><reason>Can talk right now.</reason></decline></x></message></body>
```

Also I can not figure out handler for this. What to put in strophe addHandler?
Fro group invite I have :

```
Chat.connection.addHandler(Chat.onInvite,"jabber:x:conference");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an "Action" attribute and returned it using the same namespace. My "onInvite" handler looks for the "action==='deny' and handles it accordingly.

connection().send($msg({
to: toJid, 
from: fromJid}).c('x', {
xmlns: 'jabber:x:conference', 
jid: roomJid, 
action: 'deny' }).tree());

Comment: thank you I will try this. I will keep you informed.

Comment: i have same problem as before, i can not get rid of that invite message. i have send this stanza of your but that is not working. any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I misread what you had. You need a new handler with the namespace "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user" (or MUC_USER if you have the muc plugin). Then you can grab the "decline" element and evaluate from there. After adding that, see if that gets rid of the multiple messages.